# Подключение к FTP серверу

Tags: ftp, ftp-сервер

В VirtualBox на ubuntuserver запустил ftp, но не могу подключиться через filezilla. Выдает следующие ошибки. Если подключаться не как аноним, а как пользователь ошибки те же.

Статус: Соединяюсь с 192.168.56.1...

Ответ:  fzSftp started, protocol_version=8

Команда:    open "anonymous@192.168.56.1" 22

Ошибка: Network error: Connection refused

Ошибка: Невозможно подключиться к серверу

Может кто то уже сталкивался с подобной ситуацией.

Comment: У тебя есть интернет bridge между твоим компьютером (на котором установлен VB) и самим VB?

Comment: Если есть интернет у VB, то то, к чему к ты хочешь подключиться, это web-hosting server?

Answer (score 0):

> Ошибка: Network error: Connection refused

Это значит, что на том конце, куда ты пытаешься долбиться, никто твой запрос не слушает. Хост есть, связь с ним есть, а вот указанный порт никто не слушает.

Из астрала мне подсказывают, что скорее всего по умолчанию сервер, слушает или другой IP (к примеру, 127.0.0.1, а не 192.168.56.1), или какой-то другой порт, если он вообще запустился, а то мог просто беззвучно умереть от неправильного конфига.